# in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.load

Tags: windows

I am trying to run the pyspark code from my local laptop to Oracle ADW, i have configured the wallet, jars etc. i am seeing the below error kindly help .

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.load.
: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: SO Exception was generated
```

Comment: C:\Users\Surendra\anaconda3\envs\py38\python.exe C:\Users\Surendra\PycharmProjects\test2\adwwrite.py 
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/04/11 13:06:39 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for